# Convert Sublist to Dataframe that is one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I want to convert my list into **one-column** dataframe.

```
my_data = [[red, blue], [purple], [pink, orange, black]]
```

I want my dataframe output to be like below:

```
color_column
[red, blue] 
[purple]    
[pink, orange, black]
```

**I still want each row of the dataframe **to be lists** with each element as strings**

Answer (score 0):

You can take your `list` and create a `dict` to pass to `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
my_data = [["red", "blue"], ["purple"], ["pink", "orange", "black"]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'color_column': my_data})
```

`df`:

```
            color_column
0            [red, blue]
1               [purple]
2  [pink, orange, black]
```